# Exporting Powershell REST API results as CSV

Tags: powershell, rest, invoke-command, powershell-cmdlet

I'm currently use the following Powershell script as an API call using `REST` to retrieve table data from a vendor, which appears to be in `JSON` format:

```
$uri = "https://www.SomeWebsite.com/api/orders"
$headers = @{
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer <MyTokenID>'
    'Accept'= 'application/json'
}
  
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

The script works,  and output as such in Powershell:

```
data                                                                                                                                                                    
----                                                                                                                                                                    
{@{type=appointments; id=1234; attributes=; links=; relationships=}, @{type=appointments;     id=1235; attributes=; links=; relationships=}, @{type=appointments; i...
```

I need the ability to export this as a CSV file.
How can I incorporate an`export-CSV` CMDLET (something like below) to have it work with the above syntax? (Preferably ALL Columns/Headers)

```
Select ID, Status | Export-Csv -Path "filename.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers $headers -Body $body | select -expand data | select id,status | export-csv filename.csv -notype`

Comment: Thanks ! Seems to work!  If you include this as an answer, I'll mark it as solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Invoke-RestMethod` outputs an object with a `data` property. The `data` property contains the objects you want to reference. So you must expand that property first.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers $headers -Body $body |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty data |
        Select-Object id,status |
            Export-Csv filename.csv -NoTypeInformation
```